# column value returns null instead of 0 in node js sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have used node js sequelize to do mysql operations. in attribute have done literal function to return the value. if its null its should return 0 but its return null values.

here is my code in sequelize

```
db.sequelize.literal(`(((SELECT COUNT(PR1.id) FROM CM_Poll_Results AS PR1 WHERE PR1.choice = CM_Poll_Options.id ) * 100) /(SELECT COUNT(PR2.id) FROM CM_Poll_Results AS PR2 WHERE PR2.pollId = CM_Poll_Options.pollId)) `),'percentageValue']
```

suggest the better solution for return 0 if not having values

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a SQL question than Sequelize, and will depend on your database - typically you want to avoid using `sequelize.literal()` when possible to abstract the database.

To return 0 instead of NULL for any column in MySQL, use [`IFNULL(valueOrNull, valueIfNull)`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_ifnull.asp).

```sql
SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(`column`), 0) FROM `table`
```